# Split list elements to key/val dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, split

I have this:

`query='id=10&q=7&fly=none'`

and I want to split it to create a dictionary like this:

```
d = { 'id':'10', 'q':'7', 'fly':'none'}
```

How can I do it with little code?

Answer (score 5):

By splitting twice, once on `'&'` and then on `'='` for every element resulting from the first split:

```
query='id=10&q=7&fly=none'
d = dict(i.split('=') for i in query.split('&'))
```

Now, `d` looks like:

```
{'fly': 'none', 'id': '10', 'q': '7'}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I've found also this: d = {t[0]:t[1] for t in map(lambda x: x.split("="), q.split("&"))}

Comment: @AndreaPedini True but using a `lambda` with map like that is usually quite slower. It also isn't the prettiest of constructs :-)

Answer (score 3):

In your case, the more convenient way would be using of `urllib.parse` module:

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse

query = 'id=10&q=7&fly=none'
d = {k:v[0] for k,v in urlparse.parse_qs(query).items()}
print(d)
```

The output:

```
{'id': '10', 'q': '7', 'fly': 'none'}
```

---

**Note**, that `urlparse.parse_qs()` function would be more useful if there multiple keys with same value in a query string. Here is an example:

```
query = 'id=10&q=7&fly=none&q=some_identifier&fly=flying_away'
d = urlparse.parse_qs(query)
print(d)
```

The output:

```
{'q': ['7', 'some_identifier'], 'id': ['10'], 'fly': ['none', 'flying_away']}
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
dict_query = {}
query='id=10&q=7&fly=none'

query_list = query.split("&")
for i in query_list:
    query_item = i.split("=")
    dict_query.update({query_item[0]: query_item[1]})

print(dict_query)
```

`dict_query` returns what you want. This code works by splitting the query up into the different parts, and then for each of the new parts, it splits it by the `=`. It then updates the `dict_query` with each new value. Hope this helps!